# Адаптивная верстка блоков

Tags: html, css

Вот есть блочная верстка. При изменении масштаба браузера блоки просто сужаются, а как сделать так чтобы они еще и переносились в низ друг за другом?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
}

html,
body,
.wrap-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap-content {
  display: table;
}

.slider,
.gallery,
.left-bottom-block-gallery,
.right-bottom-block-gallery {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}

.block-footer,
.block-header {
  height: 50%;
}

.block-footer {
  background: red;
}

.block-header {
  background: blue;
}

.slider {
  width: 35%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.gallery {
  width: 45%;
}

.top-block-gallery,
.bottom-block-gallery,
.top-right-bottom-block-gallery,
.bottom-right-bottom-block-gallery {
  height: 50%;
}

.top-block-gallery {
  background: #8D6E63
}

.bottom-block-gallery {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}

.left-bottom-block-gallery,
.right-bottom-block-gallery {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 50%;
}

.top-right-bottom-block-gallery {
  background: red;
}

.bottom-right-bottom-block-gallery {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-content">
  <div class="block-header">блок</div>
  <div class="block-footer">блок</div>
  <div class="slider">слайдер</div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="top-block-gallery">верхний блок галереи</div>
    <div class="bottom-block-gallery">
      <div class="left-bottom-block-gallery">нижний</div>
      <div class="right-bottom-block-gallery">
        <div class="top-right-bottom-block-gallery">блок</div>
        <div class="bottom-right-bottom-block-gallery">галереи</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем вы сделали вот это: `.wrap-content {display: table;}`?

Comment: Как сверстал, так  и работает

Comment: казалось бы, уже давно придумали бутстрап, но люди продолжают упорно изобретать свои велосипеды...

Comment: И что за `marging: 0;` у тебя в  `css`? Вторая строчка

Comment: @Klimenkomud у меня так блоки левые не съезжают

Comment: @Air ошибся margin: 0;

Comment: Для того что бы они съезжали,  есть `flex-ы`, `grid-ы` на крайняк `float-ы`, ну и естественно `@media`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если уж очень хочется переделать этот шаблон используйте media выражения. А вообще советую использовать flex.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
}

html,
body,
.wrap-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap-content {
  display: table;
}

.slider,
.gallery,
.left-bottom-block-gallery,
.right-bottom-block-gallery {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}

.block-footer,
.block-header {
  height: 50%;
}

.block-footer {
  background: red;
}

.block-header {
  background: blue;
}

.slider {
  width: 35%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.gallery {
  width: 45%;
}

.top-block-gallery,
.bottom-block-gallery,
.top-right-bottom-block-gallery,
.bottom-right-bottom-block-gallery {
  height: 50%;
}

.top-block-gallery {
  background: #8D6E63
}

.bottom-block-gallery {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}

.left-bottom-block-gallery,
.right-bottom-block-gallery {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 50%;
}

.top-right-bottom-block-gallery {
  background: red;
}

.bottom-right-bottom-block-gallery {
  background: blue;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.wrap-content, .slider, .gallery, .bottom-block-gallery, .left-bottom-block-gallery, .right-bottom-block-gallery {
  display: block;
    width: 100%
}

.slider, .gallery {
  width: 100%
}

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-content">
  <div class="block-header">блок</div>
  <div class="block-footer">блок</div>
  <div class="slider">слайдер</div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="top-block-gallery">верхний блок галереи</div>
    <div class="bottom-block-gallery">
      <div class="left-bottom-block-gallery">нижний</div>
      <div class="right-bottom-block-gallery">
        <div class="top-right-bottom-block-gallery">блок</div>
        <div class="bottom-right-bottom-block-gallery">галереи</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас сложная блочная структура, судя по вашему примеру.
В такой ситуации рекомендую использовать **Grid Layout**.

Посмотрите данный пример при разных разрешениях (просто в снипете и в сниппете на весь экран, например). Он адаптивен. Для каждого размера задаётся своё расположение элементов. Это новая возможность добавленная в Grid Layout.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header"
                       "sidebar content"
                       "sidebar content";
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .grid-container {
     grid-template-areas:  "header"
                           "content"
                           "sidebar";
  }
}

.header { 
   grid-area: header; 
   background-color: blue; 
}

.content {
   grid-area: content; 
   background-color: red;
}
 
.sidebar {
   grid-area: sidebar; 
   background-color: green; 
}

div div {
   padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="header">заголовок</div>
  <div class="content">контент</div>
  <div class="sidebar">сайдбар</div>
</div>
```

Почитать про Grid Layout - https://metanit.com/web/html5/13.1.php